# c/c++ left shift unsigned vs signed

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I have this code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned long int i = 1U << 31;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    unsigned long int uwantsum = 1 << 31;
    std::cout << uwantsum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints out.

```
2147483648
18446744071562067968
```

on Arch Linux 64 bit, gcc, ivy bridge architecture.

The first result makes sense, but I don't understand where the second number came from. 1 represented as a 4byte int signed or unsigned is

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

When you shift it 31 times to the left, you end up with

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

no? I know shifting left for positive numbers is essentially 2^k where k is how many times you shift it, assuming it still fits within bounds. Why is it I get such a bizarre number?

Comment: [bizarre number?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2147483648) check the binary form

Comment: I was talking about the second line. Updated the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Presumably you're interested in why this: `unsigned long int uwantsum = 1 << 31;` produces a "strange" value.

The problem is pretty simple: 1 is a plain `int`, so the shift is done on a plain `int`, and only after it's complete is the result converted to `unsigned long`.

In this case, however, `1<<31` overflows the range of a 32-bit signed int, so the result is undefined<sup>1</sup>. After conversion to unsigned, the result remains undefined.

That said, in most typical cases, what's likely to happen is that `1<<31` will give a bit pattern of `10000000000000000000000000000000`. When viewed as a signed 2's complement<sup>2</sup> number, this is -2147483648. Since that's negative, when it's converted to a 64-bit type, it'll be sign extended, so the top 32 bits will be filled with copies of what's in bit 31. That gives: `1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000` (33 1-bits followed by 31 0-bits).

If we then treat that as an unsigned 64-bit number, we get 18446744071562067968.

---

1. §5.8/2: 


   > The value of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. Otherwise, if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1×2E2 is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.
2. In theory, the computer could use 1's complement or signed magnitude for signed numbers--but 2's complement is currently much more common than either of those. If it did use one of those, we'd expect a different final result.

Comment: This makes sense. I wasn't sure if I was hitting undefined behavior or not. Thanks! I presume under a different compiler like msvc, I'd get something completely different?

Comment: @No_name: No guarantee, but chances are pretty decent that you'll just get what the hardware does either way, so two compilers on the same CPU will often produce the same result.

Comment: You said "both plain `int`s" - it's only the type of `1` that matters; `1 << 31ull` is the same as `1 << 31`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Good point--although technically correct as it was, this was misleading.

Comment: What does "reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type" mean?

Comment: @No_name: On most real machines, it means they keep the low order bits that would fit (e.g., with 32-bit ints, they keep the 32 low-order bits of the result).

Comment: strictly speaking it's undefined, but most implementations just apply sign extension and convert to unsigned. The result 18446744071562067968 = 0xFFFFFFFF80000000

Comment: You're assuming that `unsigned long int` is not 64 bits.   Is that true of the architecture OP described?

Comment: @Spencer: Quite the contrary, I assumed that `unsigned long int` *was* 64 bits, but `int` was 32 bits. But based on the results he showed, that's not so much an assumption as it is a conclusion based on the evidence in the question.`unsigned long int` had to be larger than 32 bits to represent the number: "18446744071562067968", but if `int` had been more than 32 bits, he'd have gotten the result he expected instead of what he actually did.

Comment: @JerryCoffin OK, I see that now. But you might want to add those deductions about type size to your answer.

Comment: @Spencer: I've added a bit more explanation about how things got from point A to point B.

Answer (score 7):

The literal `1` with no `U` is a signed `int`, so when you shift `<< 31`,  you get integer overflow, generating a negative number (under the umbrella of undefined behavior).

Assigning this negative number to an `unsigned long` causes sign extension, because `long` has more bits than `int`, and it translates the negative number into a large positive number by taking its modulus with 2<sup>64</sup>, which is the rule for signed-to-unsigned conversion.

Answer (score 3):

It's not "bizarre".

Try printing the number in hex and see if it's any more recognizable:

`std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;`

And always remember to qualify your literals with "U", "L" and/or "LL" as appropriate:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

```
unsigned long long l1 = 18446744073709550592ull;
unsigned long long l2 = 18'446'744'073'709'550'592llu;
unsigned long long l3 = 1844'6744'0737'0955'0592uLL;
unsigned long long l4 = 184467'440737'0'95505'92LLU;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is compiler dependent .
It gives same value
`2147483648
2147483648`
on my machiene (g++) .
**Proof** : http://ideone.com/cvYzxN

And if overflow is there , then because `uwantsum` is `unsigned long int` and unsigned values are **ALWAYS** positive , conversion is done from signed to unsigned by using `(uwantsum)%2^64` .

Hope this helps !

Answer (score -2):

Its in the way you printed it out.
using formar specifier %lu should represent a proper long int