# How can an integer variable show a correct value even when the value crosses its range?

Tags: c

I have executed this program on 32bit Windows 7 OS with Turbo C/C++ editor.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int a,b,c,d,e;
    clrscr();

    a = 25000;
    b = 10000;

    c = a + b;

    printf(" The value of c = %d\n", c );

    d = 5000;

    e = c - d;

    printf(" The value of e is %d\n", e );

    getch();
}
```

When I print c I get the value -30536, because the value 35000 crosses the max value. But when I use the same c in the expression 'e= c - d;' , I get the correct value as 30000.
How is this possible?

Comment: `-30536 - 5000 = 30000`

Comment: How can you justify the solution?

Comment: David.. Please elaborate your answer...how can -30536  - 5000 be equal to 30000??

Comment: Overflow/lunderflow. BTW, if you really want to learn either C or C++, use an even halfway-modern compiler.

Comment: You were happy with `25000 + 10000 = -30536`, so why not `-30536 - 5000 = 30000`?

Comment: Ulrich, will you please throw some light on the solution ?

Comment: What happens with `25000 + 10000` is the same with `-30536 - 5000`

Comment: I have not stated that I was satisfied with '25000 + 10000 = -30536' ... I wanted to show what my system gave for '25000 + 10000 '!! When the c is not holding the value 35000 how can it give 30000 after deducting 5000 ?? That's my question. If it is really holding 35000 then why it is showing -30536.

Comment: Inder.. but why is it giving the correct answer ??

Comment: @RohitS it's very simple if you think number as binary not decimal. Don't user your brain to calculate decimal user CPU's brain to calculate binary

Comment: It's not storing 35000. It's -30536. Back to basics. How can you accept `25000 + 10000 = -30536`?

Comment: Inder.. you mean to say that...25000 + 10000 = -30536 is correct??? If so ..how ??

Comment: You said it was fine. You said you understood why it happened. *When I print c I get the value -30536, because the value 35000 crosses the max value*.

Comment: In standard C your program has undefined behaviour. Your compiler is ancient and you should get a modern standard compliant compiler. And learn about undefined behaviour.

Comment: the main reason for the odd results is because the compiler you are using has a int size of 16bits, but modern hardware has an int size of either 32 or 64 bits and the underlying math is performed with the full register.

Comment: @user overflow is not restricted to 16 bit data types

Comment: don't use the ancient Turbo C anymore

Comment: and [`void main()` is also wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c?lq=1), because Turbo C existed before the first standard, it doesn't conform to the standard in many points, including `void main()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's kick the decimal and our brain and use binary and CPU.
The `int` is 16 bit here

Expression 25000 + 10000 (add the binary code very simple)

```
 01100001 10101000 = 25000
+00100111 00010000 = 10000
 10001000 10111000 = -30536
```

`10001000 10111000` is the result which is negative `30536` as first bit is signed bit

Now expression -30536 - 5000 (-30536 + (-5000) )

```
 10001000 10111000 = -30536
+11101100 01111000 = -5000 
 01110101 00110000 = 30000
```

`01110101 00110000` this result is positive `30000`

Or -30536 - 5000 you can use 2's complement method to subtract. I won't explain it here.

Comment: Both expressions are UB with 16 bit signed int. Surely you need to mention this. Or asker will think this can be relied upon.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was editing this before your comment came. Anyways thanks

Comment: I can't see mention of the UB. Now Rohit is going to think he can rely on this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can you elaborate  abbreviation `UB`. Is it Under Bound?

Comment: @RohitS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240748/allowing-signed-integer-overflows-in-c-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c