# C - Find Prime number

Tags: c

This is my prime number function and I have a problem. 
Why does it return `0` when I pass it `2147483647`?

```
int     ft_is_prime(int nb)
{
  if (nb<2)
    return (0);
  else if (nb==2)
    return (1);
  else if (nb%2==0)
    return (0);
  else 
  {
    int i=3;
    int carre=9;
    while (carre <= nb)
    {
        if (nb % i == 0)
            return (0);
        carre=carre+4*i+4;
        i=i+2;
    }
    return (1);
  }
}
```

Comment: c `int` is a 16bit datatype, you're trying to stuff a 32bit value into it.

Comment: @MarcB But sir, isn't it environment dependent? It _can_ be 32 bits also, and mostly is (on `gcc`).

Comment: @MarcB: `int` is not a single size, it can be 16-bit, it can be 32-bit, etc....

Comment: Signed integer overflow somewhere? And that is [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4240878/440558).

Comment: You should start with the value of `sizeof(int)`..

Comment: There is an overflow in the `carre`.

Comment: AKA: 'when I put 0x7FFFFFFF'.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  It is taking long time.

Comment: And there is a potential overflow on `i`.

Comment: Also on `carre` as you mentioned earlier.

Comment: `if (nb % i == 0)  return (0);` : `2147483647 % 2147483647 == 0 then return 0;`

Comment: @Veltas Optimization might refer to algorithmic optimization.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: it's still irrelevant to the question, there are well-documented better algorithms for prime number determination. OP clearly isn't interested in this, and is asking about their specific problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Eugene-Sh said, there is an overflow while computing `carre`.

Also, the standard `int` is at minimum 16bits. However most of compilers now make it 32bits. So at least you should check the limit, in order your code gets well in all the ways.

Change to `long long` to ensure you will have good result, both for `carre` and `nb`, such that you got 64 bits. But it is only half of the path. as said in a comment, you could still have an overflow when you go over this limit.

So something like this, without changing type:

```
int max = INT_MAX; // from limits.h
int maxsqrt = sqrt(INT_MAX); // cast to int, such that maxsqrt² is the max square
if (maxsqrt % 2 == 0)
   maxsqrt--; // only odd number considered
int maxcarre = maxsqrt*maxsqrt; // this is the max square (carre in french) for an odd INT
```

Then in your loop, you could now check if `carre` is the last one you can compute since maxcarre is the biggest one:

```
while (carre <= nb)
{
    if (nb % i == 0)
        return (0);
    if (carre >= maxcarre) // this is the last odd square we could compute before overflow
        return (-1); // if this -1 represents a "don't" know code for you
    carre=carre+4*i+4; // this compute the next square of an odd number 
    i=i+2;
}
```

I would recommend however to use at least `long` (and therefore changing max to `LONG_MAX`) in order to get more capacity and still in the range of the CPU (64 bits on modern compiler), or even `long long` since at least it is 64 bits on all compilers.

As @Veltas said: long is 64-bit on some 64-bit compiler implementations. It's not dependant on the OS. Also, IIRC Microsoft's VC++ uses 32-bit long on 64-bit as well.

Thanks to @Veltas, @EugeneSh. and other helping people for their precious feedback!

Comment: About size of `int` that may vary don't you think.

Comment: @FredericBrégier That's not the standard value, that's the standard **minimum** value (quoting: *Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign. § 5.2.4.2.1, ISO/IEC 9899:201x*), most implementation use 32-bits `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
/* As we know 2,3,5,7,11..19....
What is prime number
A prime number (or a prime) is a natural
number greater than 1 that has no positive
divisors other than 1 and itself.
so the formula in if we have n numbers as a input
how we find the prime number ,the formula is
divisible by 2 ...n-1. so 3%2=1 then 3 is a
prime number,10%2=0 so 10 is not a prime number 
now 9%2=1 but 9%3=0 that is why we will make a 
condition of for loop that divisible 9 with all
the numbers from 2...9-1 and find out whether it 
divisible value is 0.    
*/
int main()
{
    int i,n,j;
 bool flag;
    printf("Enter the Range Number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
        { bool flag=true;
            for(j=2;j<=i-1;j++) 
            {

                if (i%j==0){
            flag=false;
            break;}
            }
 if (flag==true)
                printf("%d\n",i);
            }

    return 0;

}
```