# What happens if you exceeds the maxium value of short int(c++)?

Tags: c++

What value will I get with this code for example,

```
short int num = 32766
num + 5 = ?
```

Maxium value for short int is 32767.

Comment: Who knows - that's why it's called "undefined behaviour"

Comment: UB is UB is a potential [release of the kraken](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7f7ba72c4f268e8).

Comment: It's probably overflow?

Comment: @synchronizer signed integer overflow is UB in c++.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Well that's interesting. I guess that I should stick to C if I want the wrapping-around then?

Comment: @synchronizer it's [UB in C too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240748/allowing-signed-integer-overflows-in-c-c)

Comment: @jaggedSpire Kraken ftw!

Comment: @jaggedSpire haha, this is awesome :D

Answer (score 4):

Signed integer overflow is [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: If I have to give it a value, would that be 0 then?

Comment: @MarkusFürst The thing about undefined behavior is that we don't know what it will be. It depends on the compiler.

Comment: @MarkusFürst don't give UB any values please, it does not deserve them, it is a nasty beast :)

Comment: @MarkusFürst that's like assigning a numeric value to a banana, except less sensible.

Comment: @MarkusFürst - You can't reason about a C++ program that is exhibiting undefined behaviour - follow that link and read about what compilers will do to such programs (and then follow the other links).