# Transition between std::chrono::seconds and std::chrono::nanoseconds without losing information

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, c++-chrono

Following this thread [nanoseconds-run-into-an-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75318139/can-stdchronodurationstdchrononanoseconds-run-into-an-overflow-i), it was my intention to transit from nanoseconds and seconds freely but without losing any information (given the fact that nanoseconds is 64 bits according to `std::chrono::nanoseconds`). Basically, the following code will lose much information:

```
std::chrono::nanoseconds t1(1705218518267805576);
std::chrono::seconds t2(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(t1));
std::chrono::nanoseconds t3(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2));
EXPECT_EQ(t1,t3);
```

The last line will return false. So, I thought about adding type such as `long_data_seconds` which can hold the lost information, but I don't know exactly how much has been lost and how can I store it for future use of transition. I would love to hear ideas.

Comment: Maybe I'm being daft but isn't the loss of information due to the fact the `std::chrono::seconds` is an *integer* (so it can't hold fractions of a second). I don't think it's about the type being too 'short' to hold the data.

Comment: *"I don't know exactly how much has been lost"* Maybe `t1 - t3`?

Comment: If you want to keep the information, you need to represent "seconds" as fractions of a second, not as integers or floating-point numbers. But then you might as well just convert when you really need the conversion.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration Durations are made from an integer type used to count the ticks and a `ratio` that is used to denote how long one tick is. `std::chrono::second` counts seconds. You cannot convert it back to nanoseconds without loosing the subseconds information. Its similar to try to make `double` ->`int` -> `double` to restore the original value

Comment: [Each of the predefined duration types up to hours covers a range of at least ±292 years](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration#Helper_types).  Is that too small for your application?

Comment: A related question: why? What problem is this supposed to solve?

Comment: If you `t1 - t3`, it'll be `267805576`.  Because `t2` is `1705218518`, and `t3` is `1705218518000000000`.

Comment: ... or rather its like trying to restore the value of `int x = some_value;` when you are only given `int y = x/1000000;`. Why do you think you need seconds -> nanoseconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are facing is not (really) due to the fact that the `std::chrono::seconds` type is not wide enough (i.e. does not have sufficient bits) to hold the full data of the `nanoseconds` value<sup>1</sup>; rather, it is because that `seconds` type is an **integer**. Thus, when you convert nanoseconds to seconds, all information on the *fractional* part of that value (i.e. data less than 10<sup>9</sup>) is lost, due to truncation.

In your case, what you will need is to define a **floating-point** duration type for your intermediate 'seconds' data. For the example you have given (1,705,218,518,267,805,576 ns), the IEEE-754 `double` type will not be sufficiently precise, so you will need a platform that supports an *extended precision* `long double` type, and use that.

Here's a short example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using ld_seconds = std::chrono::duration<long double, std::ratio<1>>;
    constexpr std::chrono::nanoseconds t1(1705218518267805576);
    constexpr ld_seconds t2(std::chrono::duration_cast<ld_seconds>(t1));
    constexpr std::chrono::nanoseconds t3(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2));

    static_assert(t1 == t3, "Not equal!");
    return 0;
}
```

And here is a demonstration on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fMY1b7o7o).

If you have a platform on which `long double` is equivalent to `double` (like MSVC/Windows), then you will need to use a third-party extended-precision library.

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, the Standard specifies that `std::chrono::seconds` have *at least* 35 bits – and many (most) current platforms don't have an in-built integer type larger than 32 bits but smaller than 64 bits, so it is likely to be an `int64_t` on those systems.